# Python: how to redirect child process output even when it contains no newline

Tags: python, cmake, subprocess

I've a `Python` script starting a process (`CMake`) and redirecting it's output to the console:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmake,my_args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in proc.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line.decode('utf-8'))
res = proc.wait()
```

This works fine and any message from `CMake` is outputed to my console.

However, at some point, the `CMake` script shows a progression using this code:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "Adding modules")
...
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "." )
...
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "done\n" )
```

This is smart and results in "Adding modules......." being displayed on a single line with a new dot added for every module processed.

But as this output has no newline untill it's done, it only gets reported by my `Python` script after the last module is added and `"done\n"` is displayed. I'd like my `Python` script to report this message dot by dot so that I can see the progression.

Is there any way to catch a sub-process output regardless if it contains new lines or not?

Note: I can modify either the `Python` or the `CMake` script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete answer:**

This is the correct code:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen([cmake,my_args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = proc.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and proc.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The `proc.stdout.read(1)` ensures the buffer size will be 1, and the `proc.poll() != None` ensures that the output won't stop when you are waiting between characters. Also, I suppose you could use `print(out, '')` instead of:

```
sys.stdout.write(out)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

but I didn't have time to test that :)

**Complicated and incomplete answer:**

This could work, but needs modifications. And it is a more "low-level" approach.

You'll need to set the `bufsize` argument inside your `subproccess.Popen` constructor. The default value is -1 which is the system default buffer which in most cases is "line buffered".

So you'll need to set `bufsize = 0` to get every character. In very io intense applications, this might result in performance issues (because read/write syscalls are expensive)

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> `bufsize` will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the `open()` function when creating the `stdin/stdout/stderr` pipe file objects:
>
> **0 means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short)**
>
> 1 means line buffered (only usable if `universal_newlines=True` i.e., in a text mode)
>
> any other positive value means use a buffer of approximately that size
>
> negative `bufsize` (the default) means the system default of `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` will be used.

Comment: Tried that, but it had no impact. I still see nothing displayed and later I get `Adding modules.........done` at once. Probably there's also something to change in the way I read `proc.stdout`?

Comment: I will try to write the code soon and check for a solution :)

Comment: Had to replace comparison to `''` to `b''` else `break` statement is never reached. Then it worked like a charm. Thank you!